# How do I use access colours and gradients on Android?

Tags: android

So i'm having a problem with using decimal colors in android.

I'm getting color codes from an external database.

For Example:

- 16777215 is white
- 16711680 is red

Now I want to use this colors to create a GradientDrawable.

```
int color = myDbReader.getColor(); //returns the decimal color code
new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {color, 0 });
```

The code example produces always a completley white gradient object.

I tried to google how to convert the decimal colors in the right way.. But i didn't find anything.

Can anyone give me a hint how to use the decimal colors in the right way?

Comment: Do you call drawable.setBounds() somewhere in your code? This call is required for every drawable in android.

Comment: @LadaRaider - actually it's not required at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your suggestions I spent last night with reading about the different types of Color codes and finally found the solution:

The given numbers are access color codes so i only have to:

```
int color = myDbReader.getColor(); //returns the decimal color code
gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {Color.rgb((value/256/256)%256, (value/256)%256, value%256), 0 });
```

Thanks four your help!

Answer (score 3):

You should read about [android colours](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

Android colors are 32bit unsigned integers, not signed ones!

Also Android colors are using Alpha bit, please read the article and the solution will be clear.

Even if SO is extremely good source of information you should google it before asking, it was the first link on Google when I entered "colour android".

BTW, I'm not an android developer.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! (and for correcting the title).  i already tried to find the solution in the android devlopers section but i was not able to find a way to convert my color codes. Maybe i'm just missing something in there!

Answer (score 0):

Android colors are ARGB units, so your color should actually consist of 4 bytes with 1 of them for the alpha value. In order to convert you can have something like this

```
0xFF000000 & yourColor
```

which will set the opacity of your color to 100%(alpha byte is set). Another option is to use `Color.parseColor` after converting your integer to a hexadecimal string. Also do not refer to colors by some magic constants. The static fields of the Color class are designed so that you don't have to do that.